# dimensions too large

Tags: tikz-pgf, compilation-error, dimensions

I'm getting the error "Dimensions too large" while they are not.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (12,0);
  \draw[-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,6);
  \foreach \x in {2,4,...,12} 
   \node at (\x,0) [below] {$\x$};
  \foreach \y in {2,4,...,6} 
   \node at (0,\y) [left] {$\y$};
  
  \draw[variable=\t,domain=-1:11,samples=1000,smooth,orange] plot ({\t},{-0.0005*(\t)^5 + (0.0066*(\t)^4) - (0.013*(\t)^3)});
 \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I should have this output:
[image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says `dimension too large` because Ti*k*Z can't compute over a certain fixed point that you reach here inside your calculation. Use `pgfplots` instead.

[image: dimension too large]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[samples=500,domain=-3:11,axis lines=middle,restrict y to domain =-2:6]
            \addplot[very thick,blue   ] plot (\x,{(-(\x)^(5))/2000+8*(\x)^(4)/1200-4*(\x)^(3)/300});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### EDIT: New solution - Ti*k*Z Workaround

The issues in your calculation are the high powers. To workaround that, it's possible to downsize the figures that are into the powers: `(0.0005^(1/5)*(\t))^5` instead of `0.0005*(\t)^5`. Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[very thin, cyan!50] (-1,-4) grid (12,6);
        \draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (12,0);
        \draw[-latex] (0,-4) -- (0,6);
        \foreach \x in {2,4,...,12} 
            \node at (\x,0) [below] {$\x$};
        \foreach \y in {2,4,...,6} 
            \node at (0,\y) [left] {$\y$};
        
        \draw[variable=\t,domain=-1:11,samples=1000,smooth,orange,line width=1pt] plot ({\t},{-(0.0005^(1/5)*(\t))^5 + (0.0066^(1/4)*(\t))^4 - (0.013^(1/3)*(\t))^3});
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Ti]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a TikZ workaround? I'm not used to pgfplots.

Comment: I edited my answer to give a Ti*k*Z only solution.

Comment: Thank you! works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

A PGFPlot solution:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=13cm, height=7cm,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-1, xmax=12,
ymin=-1, ymax=6,
]
\addplot[variable=\t, domain=-1:11, samples=100, smooth, orange] ({\t},{-0.0005*(\t)^5 + (0.0066*(\t)^4) - (0.013*(\t)^3)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with orange curve]

Comment: (same comment as above) Thank you for your answer. Is there a TikZ workaround? I'm not used to pgfplots.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pgfmath-xfp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath-xfp}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmxfpdeclarefunction{f}{1}{-0.0005*(#1)^5 + (0.0066*(#1)^4) - (0.013*(#1)^3)}
  \draw[-latex] (-1,0) -- (12,0);
  \draw[-latex] (0,-1) -- (0,6);
  \foreach \x in {2,4,...,12} \node at (\x,0) [below] {$\x$};
  \foreach \y in {2,4,...,6}  \node at (0,\y) [left] {$\y$};
  \draw[
    variable=\t,
    domain=-1:11,
    samples=1000,
    smooth,
    orange
  ] plot ({\t},{f(\t)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]